# get the width (in pt) of a box

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I would get the width (so a dimension) of a string in a box. I need to know the width of `\hphantom{some text}`, in order to use it into a tikz picture, for example as `\draw (0,0)--(\mylen,0);` that represents a line with the same width of the string `some text`.

Comment: `\settowidth{\mylen}{some text}`, assuming you already have `\newlength{\mylen}`

Comment: @egreg I need more hint: I would get the width of the chapter title, so I set `\newlength{\Titolo}` and then `\settowidth{\Titolo}{#1}`, where `#1` is the argument of `\chapter` so its title. But doing so the width seems to be zero

Comment: We need more hints from you too. What precisely do you want to do? Anyway, you need to also set the font used for the chapter title.

Comment: In general, I want to know how is the width (in pt) of a string. This would allows me to use the dimension I need into tikz environment, for example to create a line that runs from `x0` to `x0+\thewidth`. But actually I don't know `\thewidth`, and I cannot put `x_0+\hphantom{string}`.

Comment: Then `\settowidth{\mylen}{string}` will do; however you have to do `\settowidth` *outside* the `tikzpicture`, or in a `\pgfextra` instruction. But a real example of what you're trying to achieve will help.

Comment: Depending on your actual use case, you can put the text in a tikz node and use the anchors `east` and `west` to determine the width. For example is you want underline the text you can: `\node (a) {some text}; \draw (a.south east) -- (a.south west);`

Comment: Please update your question with information what you actually want to do? If you want to decorate the text `some text` there are probably better ways to do this than by measuring the text but by using the text itself in a node.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm sorry I'm late in this comment. My question is not necessary linked with tikz environment, though I need it into that. In addition, I need to recall an argument that changes trough paragraphs, because I need to measure the width of the box that contains the chapter title (and thus I must set the series, shape and family of the font). Now I'm trying to use the answers below.

Answer (score 6):

If you only have regular text in the box then TikZ can measure it too, which is what you are trying to do manually anyways. It just uses its own temporary box to measure. But `\textbf` etc. stuff is not so easy to use. So use it with caution.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\mylen{width("some text")}
\node[anchor=west,inner sep=0] {some text};
\draw[red,thick] (0,0) -- (\mylen pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Oh and `height` works too.

[image]

Comment: I think this is where this solution fails for the OP's intent of measuring the width of a chapter title, where font changing commands are probably needed. Of course this is a shot in the dark and is based only on an OP's comment.

Comment: @egreg Oops, I didn't read that part. Let me try to find a simple example.

Answer (score 3):

Declare a new box at preamble (for example). Put your object inside the box. And you can access the box width and height.

```
\newsavebox\IBox% declare a box
\savebox\IBox{some text}% put an object inside the box
% other codes...
\draw (0,0) -- (\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox) node {\usebox\IBox};% access the width, height of the box and make use of the box.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `calc` package provides the `\widthof{some text}` command with which you can measure the width of a particular string (here: *some text*). You can use it like you would use any other length in LaTeX, e.g. `2cm`.